# MVC3 and Membership API configurating

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, membership-provider

I am using default membership code that came when created new MVC app.

//Account Controller:

```
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Attempt to register the user
            MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
            Membership.CreateUser(model.UserName, model.Password, model.Email, null, null, true, null, out createStatus);

            if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false /* createPersistentCookie */);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Student");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(createStatus));
            }
        }
```

How do I prevent the user going directly to student control before registering. I have other pages that I should not allow the user to see before registering. If user tries going to page before registering I want to redirect them to the Account Controller.

Also how do I show specific pages (Actions) for specific users, in asp.net app I used the below code in the web.config file, is it something similar in mvc?

```
 <location path="Admin/Test.aspx">
   <system.web>
      <authorization>
       <deny users="?"/>
       <allow users="*"/>
     </authorization>
   </system.web>
 </location>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For Action-specific authorization, you can utilize the `[Authorize]` attribute for your Action method.  That will require the user is authenticated before being able to execute that Action method in yoru controller.

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult YourActionMethod()
{
    // your code here
}
```

As for your web.config authorization rules, you can have a web.config created in a directory for those Views that you want to secure to authorized users only (or specific groups, users, etc.).  You'll just place the web.config with the authorization rules into that directory.

Comment: Just curious do you have an example of how the web.config should be for example configuring YourActionMethod to be used for admin users only?

Comment: @user1042528 You limit an action to specific roles using the same attribute - just decorate your action with `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]`

Answer (score 0):

.NET MVC Provide the very good option - use Custome Filters and Attributes to perform check before load the Action.

For example you need to restrict acsess to some Action, so you just need to set the [Authorize] attribute on the top of that. Like this:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View();
}
```

If you want to restrict acsess to all Actions in this controller, you should just put this atribute on the top of controller class. Like this:

```
[Authorize]
public HomeComtroller : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       return View();
    }
}
```

More options, for example if you want to provide access only to user who is in the right user Role:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       return View();
    }
```